# Procedure which modifies incoming array of double by Normalizing (without using Linq)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, procedures

I've already written down the code for a procedure that modifies an incoming array of doubles by normalizing it. To normalize the array of numbers, I had to divide each number by the maximum value in the array. However, my code forces me to implement `System.Linq`

Here's my code:

```
public void Test9(double[] numbers)
{
    double MaximumNumber = numbers.Max();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] / MaximumNumber;
    }
}
```

My question, how can I achieve the same solution without implementing `using System.Linq;` at the top of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go over the array and get the maximum value first (make sure to check if there are items in the array first, so check for `numbers.Length > 0`):

```
double max = numbers[0];

for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] > max)
    {
        max = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just find the maximum by iterating the array

```
public void Test9(double[] numbers)
{
    // Find the maximum without linq
    double maxNumber = double.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
       if(numbers[i] > maxNumber) 
          maxNumber = numbers[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] / maxNumber;
    }
}
```